# My 100% w&h table expands vertically but doesn't contract on window resize

Tags: html, html-table, twitch

So I'm working on a table to hold some twitch widgets. things seem to be re-sizing properly except for vertical contraction. Everything will expand and contract horizontally, but only expand vertically. How can I fix this and keep my site re-size friendly?

Here's my code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html style="height: 99%;">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="height: 99%;">

<table width="100%" style="height: 99%;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" width="350"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=twitchraidstwitch&amp;popout_chat=true" height="99%" width="350"></iframe></td>
      <td><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="99%" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=internationalspacepimps" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=twitchraidstwitch&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object></td>
      <td rowspan="2" width="350"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=monstercat&amp;popout_chat=true" height="99%" width="350"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="99%" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=internationalspacepimps" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=twitchraidstwitch&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone suggested I change <html style="height: 99%;"> to <html> and put <style>  html {height: 99%;} </style> within head. I gave it a shot and nothing changed, then they deleted their comment before I could respond. Thanks for the suggestion though :)